# running console apps in yii2

Tags: console, console-application, yii2

I've a console controller, ImportController:

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

class ImportController extends \yii\console\Controller
{
    public function actionHeatMeter()
    {
        $this->layout = 'blank';
        return $this->render('heatmeter');
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "in the import controller!";
        //return $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

I'm trying to call it with

```
php yii import
```

No errors, no echoes, nothing.

Have I written something backwards? I feel like I am going a bit mad.

Comment: This call should echo "in the import controller", because index is default action. Seems like something wrong with your configuration. Show your console config.

Comment: Everything looks fine, do what arogachev said, also are you sure that you have checked the apache logs for errors?

Comment: Yeah - it's not echoing anything out.

Thanks guys - my config file here:

http://pastebin.com/ft64khz3

Nothing in the apache logs either..

Comment: app.log is not generating for console, either.

Comment: Try to revert to initial condition https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/console/config/main.php leaving password etc. and check the output.

Comment: Yes arogachev -pretty much,  the problem was some leftovers from a not quite right upgrade to the base yii framework code..